# inheritance , enhanced loop and arraylist not running properly

Tags: loops, inheritance, arraylist

I'm trying to put together a few things here and it isn't working correctly. I thought that each time through the loop, the loop would update and inherit for each class member. Instead, it is printing the "member" method 4 times.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class toolband
{
    public static void noise()
    {
        System.out.println("abc");
    }

static class member extends toolband
{

    public static void noise()
    {
        System.out.println("xyz");
    }
}

static class maynard extends member
{
String namemaynard = "maynard";

public static void noise() 
    {
        System.out.println("pow pow");
    }
}

static class adam extends member
{
    String nameadam = "adam";
    public static void noise() 
    {
        System.out.println("da dun da dun");
    }
}
static class danny extends member
{
    String namedanny = "danny";
    public static void noise()
    {
        System.out.println("smash smash smash");
    }
}
static class justin extends member
{
    String namejustin = "justin";
    public static void noise()
    {
        System.out.println("womp wa wa wo wo womp");
    }
}

public static void main (String [] args)
{
ArrayList <member> members = new ArrayList <member> (4);

member m = new maynard();
member a = new adam();
member d = new danny();
member j = new justin();

members.add(m);
members.add(a);
members.add(d);
members.add(j);

for (member i : members)
i.noise();

}
}
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing incorrectly. Should I be making these all static methods?

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I upvoted you but since I am new it does not record. Very much appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **noise method in toolband is static.In java static method is not overriden.**

**To make this work change noise method signature to public void noise() and same in the subclasses which override and it works.**

```
public class toolband {
    public void noise() {
        System.out.println("abc");
    }
}

class member extends toolband {

    public void noise() {
        System.out.println("xyz");
    }
}

class maynard extends member {
    String namemaynard = "maynard";

    public void noise() {
        System.out.println("pow pow");
    }
}

class adam extends member {
    String nameadam = "adam";

    public void noise() {
        System.out.println("da dun da dun");
    }
}

class danny extends member {
    String namedanny = "danny";

    public void noise() {
        System.out.println("smash smash smash");
    }
}

class justin extends member {
    String namejustin = "justin";

    public void noise() {
        System.out.println("womp wa wa wo wo womp");
    }

}
```